# How should i convert any type of date format from database to this format "d/m/Y "?

Tags: php

Is there is a way to convert one date format into another date format in PHP?

```
$date=date_create($acalib_date);              //acalib_date provides the date from database

$newdate=date_format($date,"d/m/Y");       //changing the existing date format to d/m/Y

$newDate=date('d/m/Y', strtotime(("$newdate"). " + {$inst_calib_freq_obj->inst_calibration_freq_year} year". " + {$inst_calib_freq_obj->inst_calibration_freq_month} month"));          //here i getting the final date format
```

**Note:** In one case it working correctly.

For Example: I assigned **3 years and 5 months** for calibration period. So i set start date as **12/12/2018** and the output which is return to me is **12/05/2022**.

But in case two, if set the start date as **13/12/2018** and output which is return to me is **07/02/2022** ( the original output of the return date should be **13/05/2022**, what I'd wrong here?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you asking how to change date format, or how to modify a date by a given interval (e.g. 3 years and 5 months)? Because they are two entirely different tasks.

Comment: Yes. I need to modify my date format for the given intervals! thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `12/12/2018` is actually interpretted as the American date format `month/day/year`. This is why when you specify `13/12/2018` you're getting an unexpected result.

If you instead use the `DateTime::createFromFormat` method, together with adding a `DateInterval`, you can achieve your desired result.

**Edit** - updated to support variable year and month values.

```
$years = 3;
$months = 5;

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/12/2018');
$date->add(new DateInterval("P{$years}Y${months}M"));
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '13/12/2018');
$date->add(new DateInterval("P{$years}Y${months}M"));
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Read the PHP docs for [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), and see a working example - https://3v4l.org/ioP1V

Comment: For in case if years and months are changed dynamically. how should i write the code?

Comment: @Arun - I've updated my answer to use variable values for the year and month interval.

Comment: @fuber if i use $date->format, its getting error. So I checked in phperror log. Its say "U won't use format in functions"!

Comment: @fuber Everything is working fine now.. Your method working exactly according to my need!!!! Thank you so much!!!. Three days of confusing come to an end! All credits goes to you... Once again Thanks!

Comment: @fubar In a case of leap year, Date may change know!. Then how should I write the code? I am using jquery datepicker in HTML for choosing a date.

Comment: @Arun - `DateTime` will automatically handle leap years.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

> Note that when you create a new date object using a format with
>   slashes and dashes `(eg 02-02-2012 or 02/02/2012)` it must be in the
>   `mm/dd/yy(yy) or mm-dd-yy(yy)` format (rather than british format
>   `dd/mm/yy`)! Months always before years (the american style) otherwise
>   you'll get an incorrect date and may get an error like the one above
>   (where PHP is crashing on trying to decode a `13th month`).

```
<?php


 $acalib_date = '12/13/2018';
 $date = date_create($acalib_date);
 $newdate = date_format($date,'Y/m/d');
 $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime(("$newdate") . " + {$inst_calib_freq_obj->inst_calibration_freq_year} year" . " + {$inst_calib_freq_obj->inst_calibration_freq_month} month"));
 echo $newDate;
?>
```

Comment: If $acalib_date is not static date and the years and months are also dynamic values, then how should i write the code?

Comment: Updated answer, and you can set database date format to `$acalib_date`, it work also

Comment: I changed the code exactly the way you said, but still getting same error!

Comment: for your help. this is the way i used the date format in the input field using datepicker


data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: currently unable to handle this request. HTTP 500 error

Comment: Need to check your code, it HTTP 500 because of `date_create` or something else

Comment: You can use `$newDate` variable

Comment: Yes!. I am using.